# How to open .gdocs and .gsheets from browser, when no Google client installed?

Tags: google-spreadsheets, google-drive, windows

On a computer that has Backup and Sync (formerly Google Drive) client installed, file associations are tweaked in a way that when double clicking on a document with a Google extension (for instance .gsheet or .gdoc) the default browser will be fired to open the related document, assuming the user is logged-in to Google.

Those files are really links to the online version of the document, identified by an url. 
Attempting to open this kind of file manually with a browser (in Windows "open with", will simply show the contents, for instance:

```
{"url": "https://docs.google.com/open?id=anyidhere", "doc_id": "anyidhere", "email": "account_emil@here", "resource_id": "document:anyidhere"}
```

The question is, how can you associate Google Docs file extensions on computers that have no Google client installed, to open the online version of the document? Handy in a network environment where